# Insert single variable into Oracle table

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a pretty simple question but it's stumping me. I'm using Python and I can successfully insert an entire DataFrame into my Oracle table, but when I add another `cursor.execute` statement to add an additional variable into my Oracle table it fails.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df_Quota.values]
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, sector_name, ask)" "VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, 'NEFS 2', '1')")
year_command = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(trade_year)" "VALUES (year)")
cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
cursor.execute(year_command)
con.commit() 

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

It fails on line `cursor.execute(year_command)` with the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`. A Google search reveals that this error is normally due to "including a column name in the VALUES clause"........but there are no columns in my Oracle table named "year" so I'm confused why it fails.

The variable `year` contains a year btw, in this case "2014".

Any help shedding light on this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: in your year_command string, "year" is just a string, not a reference to a variable. Seems like you'll need to do whatever Python likes for variable substitution in a sql statement.

Comment: Are you positive that it's a string? I might be wrong but I was under the assumption that to import a string it would have to be in quotes, like at the end of my `sql_query` line

Comment: my python skills are both weak and dated, but I'd be really impressed if python can somehow know which random word in a string it should replace automatically with any arbitrary variable name. Try concatenating the value of the year variable into the string.

Comment: You used bind variables in your first statement. So should you not just bind the value of year into a bind variable in your second, in just the same way?

Comment: @BobC Forgive me for being a noob but I don't fully understand what a bind variable is... I had a little help writing my first statement so I don't understand what they did forwards and backwards. Would you mind explaining what exactly you mean by making it a bind variable?

Comment: @theprowler. A bind variable is basically just a fancy name for a parameter. In your first query, the :1, :2 ... etc are all parameters. Their value are actually provided (bounded, hence "bind" variable) earlier in your python code.

Comment: Ohhh ok.... So if I was to make an additional line of code before the `year_command` line that said something like `new_variable = year.value` and then write `cursor.executemany(year_command, new_variable)` that could work?........ EDIT: it didn't work, it says that the `'str' object has no attribute 'value'`...which confuses me because `year` is a variable not a string